# cheap stereo vision camera + opencv

Tags: opencv, synchronization, javacv, stereo-3d

I'm trying to make an application that uses stereo vision with 20fps with javacv/opencv. I've seen some camera sterio vision, but all are expensive. I heard already talking about the Minoru 3D? Anyone know if it works with javacv?

Does anyone have any idea what kind of is camera used for products like [this](http://www.trafsys.com/traf-sys-vision-apex-stereo-precision-people-counting)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything special. I worked as a research assistant in my university's robotics lab as an undergrad and doing things on the cheap was almost part of the job-description.

For stereo-vision all you need are two cameras... that's it! Ideally of the same specification, but using heterogeneous cameras might require a lot of work to get good results, especially if they have different optical characteristics (as opposed to just sensor size, resolution, and RGB sensitivity).

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have no experience with stereo vision, but if I use two cameras of the same model I must ensure that all frames are synchronized between the two cameras and when I see the use of two cameras to create sterio vision, video do not see high-framerate. I saw this article http://letsmakerobots.com/node/29869 that shows how to synchronize two camera via hardware, but I have no experience to do what the article proposes. It is possible to use two cameras and get at least 10 frames per second synchronized the cameras via software?

Comment: Hum, this really depends on the type of application. If the stereo images are consumed by robot software for navigation maybe it's sufficient. If the videos are to be consumed by humans, for a stereoscopic display, you will need more than just two cameras of the same spec. You will need subframe accurate sync, camera alignment, possibly radiometric matching.