# OpenCV cheap stereo camera can't load both streams at once

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have purchased an [ELP-1MP2CAM001](http://www.elpcctv.com/dual-lens-usb-camera-module-ov9712-color-cmos-sensor-p-236.html) which shows up as two webcam devices on Windows. If I open the Windwos default "Camera" app and Skype I can display the feeds from both the left and right camera at the same time. I don't think therefore it is a USB Bandwidth issue with two cameras coming into the same port

I'm using fairly standard code (shown below) to open both of these feeds and it works successfully if I use two standard Microsoft HD3000 webcams instead of the single stereo camera.

I've tried a range of numbers inside the `cap2()` arguments so I don't think it's hiding at number 10 or anything weird like that.

My questions are:

1. There must be some sort of on board hub for the ELP cameras, do I need to do something different in OpenCV?
2. Could it be that both frames are accessible through `cap(0)`? This seems unlikely to me.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138897/cheap-stereo-vision-camera-opencv) questions says I don't need to do anything special? but obviously I'm missing something.

Any help on this would be great.

---

**Code:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{


    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    VideoCapture cap2(1); // open the default camera

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);

    cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
    cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    if (!cap2.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat frame;
    Mat frame2;
    namedWindow("Frame", 1);
    namedWindow("Frame2", 1);

    for (;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        imshow("Frame", frame);

        Mat frame2;
        cap2 >> frame2;
        imshow("Frame2", frame2);





        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break; // Finish on "esc" key
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any update on this issue? The accepted answer below does not work.

Comment: TBH I gave up pretty quickly with the cheap stereo camera. If you're using two cameras make sure you have enough USB bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same camera as this, and I ran into the same problem before. Try change the order of your code as below:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
VideoCapture cap2(1);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 240);
cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
```

I think it's a problem with USB bandwidth. In your code, you opened two cameras in full resolution at the beginning, then you change the resolution of two cameras.

When you call `VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera`, `cap` has resolution `1280*720`. `cap` already occupied the bandwidth. Thereby, `VideoCapture cap2(1);` won't open camera `cap2` sucessfully.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's super interesting! I no longer have the camera but seems like a very sensible solution. If it worked for you I think i'll go ahead and accept.

Comment: This answer does not work but I appreciate the suggestion though to reduce the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

According to [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146) documentation, there is a function called `cv::VideoCapture::grab`:

> The primary use of the function is in multi-camera environments, especially when the cameras do not have hardware synchronization. That is, you call `VideoCapture::grab()` for each camera and after that call the slower method `VideoCapture::retrieve()` to decode and get frame from each camera

You can try that, with:

```
cap.grab();
cap.retrieve(...);
```

Comment: This seems like a very sensible solution, I have had a breif play but nothing yet. I've bought some other cameras in the meantime so work is progressing on those. I will update if I get anywhere

Comment: Hmm the main problem seems to be that cap2(1) doesn't actually return true at all...